# ngrok speed became slow

Tags: tunnel, ngrok

Ive been using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to test an app on my phone, with react-native for the past 2 weeks.  And so far its been pretty decent and quick.

Until today.
Now it suddenly takes about 50 seconds for a request to make a roundtrip from my phone, to my localhost and back.  Or from my browser, to the ngrok tunnel, back to my localhost.

At first I thought, ok ngrok is either down or experiencing slowdowns. But then I decided to hit it with Postman, and with that the request is fast.  Around 0.5 seconds.  Same when I access the tunnel stats.  A replay request is like 1second.

Just when I do it over my phone, or browser its now extremely slow.
Is there any specific reason this may suddenly be occuring?
Can anyone shed any light on where I should even begin looking?

I've tried rebooting, and flushing DNS, to no avail.

Comment: They are announced closing their free plan, so it seems, that it could be related. I have the same issue

Comment: seeing the same thing, +1

Comment: still happening on the paid plan...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Lol did you guys get anything?

Comment: Same here in 2020 .------.

Comment: same (2021) 15char

Comment: Similar experience in 2021. Even with the upgraded account.

Comment: Maybe the network bandwidth from the exposed server was too low. However with 500MBi speed, I would assume to work.

Answer (score 15):

This can be optimized by selecting the datacenter closest to you. If you are for example from Germany, so you should be using the EU region to minimize any latency. To start your tunnel using the --region tag:

```
ngrok http --region eu <port>
```

Here's more about the global datacenter regions: https://ngrok.com/docs#global

Comment: Also adding the ```--inspect=false``` flag helps to improve the speed.

Comment: Now ngrok needs two "-" for the property to work. This would be the correct: `ngrok http --region eu <port>`

Answer (score -2):

Based on Tenarius answer, Change to another region, and then change again to the nearest datacenter. it works for me

Comment: This is more suitable to be in the comment section than a seperate answer.